# MySQL delete entries based on last two digits of Unix/Epoch time

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three columns:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment    
  `tm` int NOT NULL    
  `ip` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0'
```

I want to run a query that will check if the same IP was logged within a minute and then delete all but one of those entries.

For example I have the two rows below.

```
id=1 tm=1361886629 ip=192.168.0.1
id=2 tm=1361886630 ip=192.168.0.1
```

I would only like to keep one in the database.

I have read lots of other remove duplicate/partial duplicate entry questions but I'm looking for a way to compare the last two digits of the Unix/epoch time and delete all but one based on that plus the IP.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CAST` in mysql to remove the last 2 digits

```
SELECT CAST( tm AS CHAR( 8 ) )
```

this will select only the first 8 digits from the timestamp and allow you to find duplicates

if you only want to know what the last 2 digits are

```
SELECT RIGHT(CAST( tm AS CHAR( 10 ) ), 2)
```

this will select the last two digits only from each timestamp

Comment: Interesting I will have a look at CAST and let you know, Thanks